# How to serve up images in Angular2?

Tags: html, angular, image, typescript, path

I am trying to put the relative path to one of my images in my assets folder in an image src tag in my Angular2 app. I set a variable in my component to 'fullImagePath' and used that in my template. I have tried many different possible paths, but just cannot seem to get my image up. Is there some special path in Angular2 that is always relative to a static folder like in Django ?

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero',
  templateUrl: './hero.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hero.component.css']
})

export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {
  fullImagePath: string;

  constructor() {
    this.fullImagePath = '../../assets/images/therealdealportfoliohero.jpg'
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I also put the picture into the same folder as this component, so since the template, and css in the same folder is working I'm not sure why a similar relative path to the image is not working. This is the same component with the image in the same folder.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero',
  templateUrl: './hero.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hero.component.css']
})

export class HeroComponent implements OnInit {
  fullImagePath: string;

  constructor() {
    this.fullImagePath = './therealdealportfoliohero.jpg'
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <img [src]="fullImagePath">
    </div>
</div>
```

app tree * I left out the node modules folder to save space

```
├── README.md
├── angular-cli.json
├── e2e
│   ├── app.e2e-spec.ts
│   ├── app.po.ts
│   └── tsconfig.json
├── karma.conf.js
├── package.json
├── protractor.conf.js
├── src
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── app.component.css
│   │   ├── app.component.html
│   │   ├── app.component.spec.ts
│   │   ├── app.component.ts
│   │   ├── app.module.ts
│   │   ├── hero
│   │   │   ├── hero.component.css
│   │   │   ├── hero.component.html
│   │   │   ├── hero.component.spec.ts
│   │   │   ├── hero.component.ts
│   │   │   └── portheropng.png
│   │   ├── index.ts
│   │   └── shared
│   │       └── index.ts
│   ├── assets
│   │   └── images
│   │       └── therealdealportfoliohero.jpg
│   ├── environments
│   │   ├── environment.dev.ts
│   │   ├── environment.prod.ts
│   │   └── environment.ts
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── main.ts
│   ├── polyfills.ts
│   ├── styles.css
│   ├── test.ts
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   └── typings.d.ts
└── tslint.json
```

Comment: Why do you want to use relative path? Can't we set it to start from root (i.e. `this.fullImagePath = '/assets/images/therealdealportfoliohero.jpg'`)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. How does the application know where the root is ? Is it the project root, or is it always assets for static files like css, images, and javascript ?

Comment: Yea it really depends on your setup though. For me, I separate assets off the code part (by having different gulp tasks for them) so I'll know exactly where the assets are.

Comment: Phwew, finally got it to work Harry. You were right about using the full path. The reason it wasn't working was an issue I've had in the past when using photoshop, and not exporting images from there correctly. Argghhh Photoshoppppp ! Anyway Thanks Harry !

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Angular only points to `src/assets` folder, nothing else is public to access via url so you should use full path

```
 this.fullImagePath = '/assets/images/therealdealportfoliohero.jpg'
```

Or

```
 this.fullImagePath = 'assets/images/therealdealportfoliohero.jpg'
```

This will only work if the base href tag is set with `/`

You can also add other folders for data in `angular/cli`.
All you need to modify is `angular-cli.json`

```
"assets": [
 "assets",
 "img",
 "favicon.ico",
 ".htaccess"
]
```

Note in edit :
Dist command will try to find all attachments from assets so it is also important to keep the images and any files you want to access via url inside assets, like mock json data files should also be in assets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me a lot.
I would appreciate it if your could tell me where in the official docs is this documented?

Comment: Angular projects made with angular-cli track where assets can be served from in the `.angular-cli.json` file.  See @michal-ambrož answer for more information.

Comment: Thx! ...when you've been playing around with Angular for months and suddenly you realize you haven't yet had to add a single image ;-)

Comment: "This will only work if the base href tag is set with /" What do I need to do if my base href needs to be setup to another path because my app will run in a subdirectory on the server?

Comment: It will find the assets folder in that directory so there will be no issue I think

Comment: helpful, thanks !

Answer (score 11):

If you do not like assets folder you can edit `.angular-cli.json` and add other folders you need.

```
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "img",
    "favicon.ico"
  ]
```

Comment: Why if I add `"assets": [
        "assets",
        "assets/images",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],` it still doesn't work?

Answer (score 4):

Add your image path like `fullPathname='assets/images/therealdealportfoliohero.jpg'` in your constructor. It will work definitely.

Answer (score 2):

I am using the Asp.Net Core angular template project with an Angular 4 front end and webpack. I had to use  '/dist/assets/images/' in front of the image name, and store the image in the assets/images directory in the dist directory.
eg:

```
 <img  class="img-responsive" src="/dist/assets/images/UnitBadge.jpg">
```

Comment: But when you're in development, this wouldn't work right?

Comment: @davaus probably because you already did a build so your old 'dist' is just sitting there. If you update an image it isn't going to be refreshed until you build.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just put your images in the assets folder refer them in your `html` pages or `ts` files with that link.

Answer (score 1):

In angular only one page is requested from server, that is index.html. And index.html and assets folder are on same directory. while putting image in any component give src value like `assets\image.png`. This will work fine because browser will make request to server for that image and webpack will be able serve that image.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

for the div background image

```
<div style="min-height: fit-content;
background-image: url('/assets/Get-started-section.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position:center;
width: 100%; ">
</div>
```

And for the img

```
 <img src="/assets/Get-started-section.jpg"/>
```