# path navigate into folders angular

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying write the path of the local images into the project and It seems to show me an undefined image.
[image]

as you can see I'm in the app.component.html
I want to make

```
src="img/profile.png"
```

but in the browser I get this error

```
profile.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

do I wrong with the path?

Comment: Hi Adir,
From your screen grab src="img/profile.png" path is not correct. So try with the path src="img/portfolio/profile.png". I hope this is your solution

Comment: no, the profile.png not into the portfolio, it's into the img

Comment: @MalathyVenkatesan actually I don't think it is - if you look carefully that folder is not expanded. When setting the src I believe it is relative to the `<base href>` in your `index.html` can you check that? You may also want to try putting it in an assets folder as [the top answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230473/how-to-serve-up-images-in-angular2) suggests

Comment: Try this solution
 src="/img/profile.png"

Answer (score 4):

You need to create this `img` folder in assets which is out of `src` folder. And then try to use that path like below

```
<img src="./assets/img/profile.png">
```

Answer (score 3):

I found solution for that works.
I just move the folder img to assets and then I write this line

```
src="assets/img/profile.png"
```