# Resource not found, wrong path?

Tags: html, angular, path

Am I using the wrong path to load in an image that I downloaded? I am trying to load frank.jpg from about-user.component.html. [image]

Why am I getting a 404 not found error for the resource?

Comment: put image in assets folder

Comment: then call it using src of image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the assets array in .angular-cli.json to list files or folders you want to copy as-is when building your project.

By default, the src/assets/ folder and src/favicon.ico are copied over.

```
"assets": [
  "assets",
  "favicon.ico"
]
```

**make one image folder in assets**

**put your image in that folder**

**then in angular-cli.json**

```
"assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "static/images"
      ]
```

images is folder name
then give path like `../assets/images/frank.png` in src

Comment: glad to help you

Comment: To reference this image do I navigate to it as I was before?

Comment: assets is like your resource folder, you can put every image which you want to use in that assets/image folder. only once you have to edit angular-cli.json

Comment: @FrankTheTank didnt understood your question? can you explain more clearly?

Answer (score 1):

Any image you use need to be put in the `assets` folder. You can then access the images from there.

Check this link on [how to access images from `assets` folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230473/how-to-serve-up-images-in-angular2).