# Trying to add src in image, but don't know how to write path

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, image

So I am working on a MEAN stack app and I just learned how to upload an image and save it in a file, but now I don't know how to get to use this image path inside an img element. First I'll post a screenshot that shows the structure of my app:

[image]

I have saved my uploaded images in the public/uploads folder. Public is at the same level of the asset folder which contains all the angular stuff.

In the template I showed above `profilePicLink` would be '../../../public/uploads/' + result.user.profilePicture.name. This unfortunately  doesn't work. It doesn't show the image.

I assume I need to change the path, but I don't know what path I need to get the image inside my img element.

Could you guys help me?

Comment: Please post actual code instead of pictures of code

Comment: Use assets folder to serve images, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230473/how-to-serve-up-images-in-angular2/42660412