# Angular 5 - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular5

I'm trying to get a svg image from a package in node_modules, I installed from my private local npm registry, the package downloaded and exists under my node_modules of the project, my html code is like this

```
<img src="/src/assets/images/my-image.svg">
```

as I use a little script in `angular-cli.json` file to pass assets from node_modules to this local assets folder.
and I have the **"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"**
I verified that the image exists on node_modues and I can preview it, i'm using angular/cli 1.6.8

Update:

Angular doesn't access assets on `node_modules` folder, but I find a way how to do it, by using this code:

```
"assets": [
    { "glob": "**/*",
      "input": "../node_modules/my-private-package.assets/",
      "output": "./assets/" },
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ]
```

In the angular-cli.json, but still cannot access these assets and still says same error.

Comment: copy the svg to a folder in the app and load it from there

Comment: what's your path to the html in which you are trying to get this module?. pretty sure that your svg is not loaded because of wrong path.

Comment: copy image to assets folder and use from there

Comment: @Roysh when I use it locally it works. but this is not the purpose

Comment: i don't think you're suppose to load svgs this way. 
however, you have some syntax issues -> `<\img` should be `<img` and `src` should be `[src]`

Comment: @haifzhan I added the backslash, just to show the code, as it's html, it's gonna be interpreted by the browser

Comment: @VinkoVorih I verified the path, used the absolute and the relatif one and didn't work, and i'm using an IDE that generate the path automatiacally, so nowrong path

Comment: @KaushikAndani this isn't the purpose

Comment: @Roysh if you put squared brackets you are binding some variable from typescript and that is automatically wrong.

Comment: can you share actual structure and settings of you app? so we can understand actually what is wrong

Comment: Angular only points to src/assets folder, nothing else is public to access via URL.

Comment: @Vikas thanks vikas, is there another way to make this accessible, as i want to use local packages to share same assets to multiple applications !!!

Comment: Refer this https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration

Answer (score 2):

The `node_modules` folder is for dependencies, not assets (like an svg) that you are using in your application.

Try putting the image file in the assets folder then link to it like this:

```
<img src="/assets/my-image.svg">
```

I.E. when you run ng build, the angular CLI will compile your files in a `dist` folder. Notice the `assets` folder is in there. The `node_modules` folder is not.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue with your source.
node_modules is outside of the src folder. It should be ../node_modules. 
try below code,

```
<img src="../node_modules/my-private-packages/images/my-image.svg">
```

Comment: Not possible, Angular only points to src/assets folder, nothing else is `public` to access via URL.

Comment: why do so ?? it won't work as node_modules is in the root folder

Comment: have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230473/how-to-serve-up-images-in-angular2

Comment: Please stop adding salutations to your posts, see e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/248731

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best way to get the image.

```
<div>
    <img src="assets/images/dashboard.svg">
</div>
```