# Dynamic image with relative path

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to add local image icon with relative path. setting dynamic icon with relative path but getting Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../content/images/{{imageList[item.type]}}'. Using **require** variable image path working fine.

Assets/images
imageA
imageB
imageC

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
export class PhishingDetailsComponent implements OnInit{
  public imageList: any = {'A': 'imageA.png', 'B': 'imageB.png', 'C': 'imageC.png'};
  public itemList: any = [{id: 11, type: 'A'}, {id: 21, type: 'B'}, {id: 101, type: 'B'}, {id: 121, type: 'D'}];
  public images: any = {
   'A': require('../../images/imageA.png'),
   'B': require('../../images/imageB.png'),
   'C': require('../../images/imageC.png')
  };
}
```

html:

```
 <div class="well">
  <div *ngFor="let item of itemList">
   <img [src]="images[item.type]" /> // this is working fine.
   <img src="../../images/{{imageList[item.type]}}" /> // this is not working.
  </div>
 </div>
```

but getting compilation error. plz help me to correct way to use. Thanks.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to serve up images in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230473/how-to-serve-up-images-in-angular2)

Comment: I'm getting Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../content/images/{{imageList[item.type]}}'.

Comment: Thanks @Vega, it's my mistake i forget images extension. suppose img ext is there but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<div class="well">
  <div *ngFor="let item of itemList">
   <img class="correlation-icon" src="/assets/images/{{imageList[item.type]}}" />
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: unable to set absolute path, i've relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Html File

```
<div class="well">
  <div *ngFor="let item of itemList">
   <img class="correlation-icon" src="../assets/images/image{{item}}.svg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

BackEnd

```
public itemList: any =['A','B','C','D']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your  item.type doesn't contain the full image name.

Try this:

```
 <img src="../../images/{{'image'+imageList[item.type]+'.png'}}" /> // should work :)
```

Comment: no this will not resolve the correct path. it's produce Error: Can't resolve.

Comment: Then, keeping the above, adjust the relative path. remove ../ or just ... Also put images in assets/images next to /app, inside /src et change to "/assets/images/..." and test. if the later works, then it's just inaccessible and you have to change the directory. hope it's clear