# Failed to load the resource: the server ... responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular

I have strange error in my angular project. I tried to create relative path to an image. In `app.component.ts` I have code like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})

export class AppComponent  {
    imagePath = require("./Angular2Demo/Angular2/src/app/images/angular_logo.png");
}
```

In `app.component.html` a have code like this:

```
<img class="logo" [src]="imagePath" />
```

When I start my project, there is error in:

Failed to load the resource: the server (path to the image...)/angular_logo.png.js responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

This path should be good, but I don't know why the image has extension .png.js, why not only .png? In my folder the image has only .png extension... Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: See the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36287518/angular-2-img-src-in-a-relative-path

Comment: I saw that post, I did everything like this, but I have problem with this .js extension, that is different problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do

`imagePath = './images/angular_logo.png';`

or

`imagePath = './assets/images/angular_logo.png';`

if your `images` folder is inside the `assets` folder in your project.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just:

```
imagePath = './Angular2Demo/Angular2/src/app/images/angular_logo.png';
```

I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish by using `require`. `require` is what is adding the ".js" extension, and it won't return you a path either -- it will attempt to load JavaScript and return a JavaScript object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem is that I don't need this part: .Angular2Demo/Angular2/src. But your point have sense. ;-)